# How to count all lines with BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I just got stuck with this BufferedReader and I can't make it to read the whole txt file..it reads only the first line!

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("/Users/esson/Desktop/sonnets/sonnet3.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String input = br.readLine();
List<String> output= (List) Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));

for(String word: output) {
    int times = Collections.frequency(output, word);
    System.out.println("" + word+ " -- "+times);
```

and the output is:

```
When -- 1
most -- 1
I -- 1
wink -- 1
then -- 1
do -- 1
mine -- 1
eyes -- 1
best -- 1
see, -- 1
```

Comment: [Java !== Javascript](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/).

Comment: Look at how many times you're calling `readLine`. Why would you expect that code to read more than one line?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put BufferedReader.readLine() in a loop. For example:

```
while((text = BufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
```

Also, I think you should tag the question as Java and not Javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
int lineNum;

for(String word: output) {

     lineNum++;

     int times = Collections.frequency(output, word);
     System.out.println("" + word+ " -- "+times);
 }

 System.out.println("Line Number is " + lineNum);
```